# Wordpress Plugin how to suppress admin header

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for Wordpress, I need to export a file from the system, but i can workout how to suppress the admin headers.

An example of the code is:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'myplugin_setup');
function myplugin_setup(){
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'myplugin', 'myplugin_admin_main', 'dashicons-admin-users' );
    add_submenu_page( 'myplugin', 'My Plugin Export', 'My Plugin Export', 'manage_options', 'myplugin-export', 'myplugin_admin_export' );
}

function mcm_profiles_admin_main(){
    print('<h1>My Admin Page</h1>');
}

function myplugin_admin_export(){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=myexportfile.txt');
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');

    print('Contents of file')
}
```

I'd like `myplugin_admin_export` to output a file with "Content of file" inside, but its displaying an admin page.

Is there a way in Wordpress to suppress the admin content.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
readfile('myexportfile.txt');
exit;
```

And let me know if it works?